# How to display Multiple Lines in WebView of android if the user gives input as Hi↵↵Hello ↵↵Good ↵↵Morning

Tags: android-webview

webView.loadData("Hi \n Hello \n Good \n Morning", "text/html", "UTF-8");

Here the String which as given as input it not displaying in multiple lines.

Please anybody suggest a solution for this...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the ↵ character with an HTML `<br />` tag.